# C# Get property values from an Object

Tags: c#, object, properties, .net-core-3.1

Throughout my WebApp project, i'm logging the details of the current user across most of the controller/razor page model methods. I moved the code used for retrieving the current user into a repository and return an object to the calling method.

I'm not sure how to get the values of the properties returned in the object.

Class:

```
public class CurrentUser : ICurrentUser
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CurrentUser(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public class CurrentUserProperties
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public object GetCurrentUser()
    {
        CurrentUserProperties currentUser = new CurrentUserProperties
        {
            Id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value,
            Username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
            Forename = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value,
            Surname = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value
        };
        return currentUser;
    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
object currentUser = _currentUser.GetCurrentUser();
```

[image]

I'm looking to use the least amount of code possible to get the values of these properties returned given I'll be using this for most methods throughout the application, thanks

Comment: Why are you returning type `object` rather than type `CurrentUserProperties`?

Comment: You should probably return a `CurrentUserProperties` type from `GetCurrentUser`. Otherwise, you can cast the return value to the correct type: `CurrentUserProperties currentUser = (CurrentUserProperties) _currentUser.GetCurrentUser();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments from 'Rufus' the code below did the trick, thanks

```
CurrentUserProperties currentUser = (CurrentUserProperties)_currentUser.GetCurrentUser();

        var userId = currentUser.Id;
        var username = currentUser.Username;
        var forename = currentUser.Forename;
        var surname = currentUser.Surname;
```